# Sending SMS from phone to website in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: sms, tweets

I want to give users ability to post short text messages from their phones to my site.
Anyone has any experience with this or how it can be done?
Any sample code or tutorial will be helpful.

Basically any tweet from specific user would go to his channel where visitor can see his tweets. User can tweet from the site as well which is easy to handle.

This tweeting thing is a totally new programming area for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Twilio. It's incredibly cheap and easy to use!

:)

http://www.twilio.com/

Comment: Additionally, it gives YOU the ability to send messages to your clients too, so you could send a mass text-message or voice call to all numbers in your database at a low cost. They also support OpenVBX and other great tools. (PS I don't work for them haha)

Comment: That is not what I am looking for though. But great tool. I like the voice mail part of it. I might need to write own code someday for that. I thought you work for them! Thanks Seth

Comment: I think it does do what you need. You get a phone number from Twilio, when a message is sent to that number, we make a POST to your server. Here's an example of a group messaging system using ASP.NET MVC: http://blog.twilio.com/2010/04/howto-build-a-group-sms-application-with-aspnet-mvc.html